# Prove that $x^n(1−x)^n$ has its maximum at x=1/2.

Tags: calculus

I was trying to prove that $f_n(x)=x^n(1-x)^n$ converges uniformly on [0,1], and found this: [Convergence of $f_n(x)=x^n(1-x)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2868006/convergence-of-f-nx-xn1-xn)
But I've got stuck on how to prove that $f_n(x)$ has a maximum on 1/2. Can you guys give me an idea?

Comment: HINT: $$\max_{x \in [0,1]} [x(x-1)]^n = [ \max_{x \in [0,1]} x(x-1)]^n$$

Comment: first show $x(1-x)\leq \frac 14$ and attains the max at $x = \frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Thank you, @Crostul

Comment: Thank you too @dezdichado :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather mechanical (not especially clever or elegant way). The derivative is

$$f'=n x^{n-1}(1-x)n - n x^n(1-x)^{n-1}=nx^{n-1}(1-x)^{n-1}(1-2x)$$

This is zero only at $x=0$, $x=1/2$, $x=1$. It's easy to see that the first and last are minima, and $x=1/2$ is the global maximum.

Answer (score 3):

**Without derivatives:**

Let $x=t+\frac12$. Then

$$x^n(1-x)^n=\left(t+\frac12\right)^n\left(\frac12-t\right)^n=\left(\frac14-t^2\right)^n.$$

The expression inside the parenthesis is maximized in $[-\frac12,\frac12]$ when $t=0$, and so is its $n^{th}$ power.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a non calculus way, Using AM-GM for 2n variables yields the inequality $$x^n(1-x)^n≤(\frac{x*n+(1-x)*n}{2n})^{1/n}=2^{1/n}$$ which is only equal when all the terms are equal, namely $x=1-x$ or $x=0.5$

Answer (score 1):

As @Crostul already pointed out, you can use a trick.

For any strictly increasing function $f(x)$, and you want to find the maximum of $f(x)$ on any domain, it is enough to find the maximum value of $x$ on the domain and apply $f(x)$ on that value. (Because the largest x will result in the largest $f(x)$.

with $f(x) = x^n$ (for positive $n$), we can rewrite your problem:

$$max(x^n \cdot (1-x)^n) = max[(x\cdot(1-x))^n]  = max[x\cdot(1-x)]^n$$
We know that we only need to find the maximum of $x\cdot(1-x)$ which is at $x=0.5$

Answer (score 1):

Overkill:

$x=\sin^2 t$, $0\le t \le π/2$;

$F(t)= (\sin^2 t)^n(1-\sin^2 t)^n$;

$F(t)= (\sin^2 t \cos^2 t)^n$;

$F(t)=(1/4)^n(\sin^2 2t)^n$;

$F_{max}$ at $t=π/4$, then

$x=\sin^2 (π/4)= (1/√2)^2=1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
if
$f(x) = x^a(1-x)^b
$
where
$a, b \ge 1$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
f'(x)
&=ax^{a-1}(1-x)^b-x^ab(1-x)^{b-1}\\
&=x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}(a(1-x)-bx)\\
&=x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}(a-x(a+b))\\
\end{array}
$

so
$f'(x) = 0$
at 
$x = \dfrac{a}{a+b}
$
when

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=(\dfrac{a}{a+b})^a(1-\dfrac{a}{a+b})^b\\
&=(\dfrac{a}{a+b})^a(\dfrac{b}{a+b})^b\\
&=\dfrac{a^ab^b}{(a+b)^{a+b}}\\
\end{array}
$

If $a=b$,
the max is at $\dfrac12$
and the value is
$\dfrac{a^{2a}}{(2a)^{2a}}
=\dfrac{1}{2^{2a}}
$.